# same uuid two times + Vuex + uuidv4()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, uuid

I have inside my vuex store a function to create a post. And the function returns a json Object with a unique uuid from `uuidv4()`. But if I run the function two times (or more) I get the same uuid and that's a problem.
(Only if I reload the page I get a new uuid).

```
// store.js
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';
var uuid = uuidv4();
const state = {
  postDetails: {
    ...
    uuid:  uuid,
    ...
  }
}

const actions = {
  post ({state}) {
    var postArray = []
    postArray.push(state.postDetails)
    // some axios stuff...
  }
}
```

So everything works fine. The main problem is the uuid which doesn't change after the function is called.

I use `vuex-persistedstate` also

Comment: Where is `uuidv4()` defined?

Comment: yes sorry: uptated

Answer (score 0):

## for those who need this

Solved my problem. I have added a function which creates a uuid without page reload.

```
function uuidv44() {
  return ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  )
}
```

With help from this site [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript?rq=1)